# How do you obtain an @ubuntu.com email address?

Tags: thunderbird, email, ubuntu-email-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Ubuntu membership?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16403/how-to-get-ubuntu-membership)

I recently saw  the question "How to add an @ubuntu.com email address in Thunderbird" and wondered how one obtains an @ubuntu.com email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be an Ubuntu member, check https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership .

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find some more informations: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuEmail