# Does contributing on Ask Ubuntu help me to become an Ubuntu Member?

Tags: ubuntu-membership

Can I become an Ubuntu Member from earning reputation on Ask Ubuntu? If I can, is there a minimum reputation I need to achieve?

Is asking and answering a good way or is something else required?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Ubuntu membership?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16403/how-to-get-ubuntu-membership)

Comment: @JorgeCastro: only the lowest answer mentions AU. I think there is a need for this more specific question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Becoming an Ubuntu Member is *completely* achievable through contributions here.
I can say that because it's how I became an Ubuntu Member.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16403/how-to-get-ubuntu-membership) outlines what you need to do but it's not a prescribed system. **The most important thing is *demonstrating sustained contribution***. It doesn't really matter where you do that.

[My Ubuntu Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Oli) should give you some sort of indication how you can use your activity on Ask Ubuntu to show a membership board that you're contributing to Ubuntu. If they agree that your contributions are significant enough, you become a member.
If they don't, you don't. Simple as that.

But yes... Contributing here by answering questions (more useful than asking IMO) and helping with the review side of things are perfectly decent ways of contributing to the wider Ubuntu community. They're also fairly simple to turn into statistics. My Wiki page has a link to a few Data.SE queries that should help you.

You can see more about the specific how-to-apply stuff on the [new member guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership/NewMember). That should also give you some indication of how much work you'll need to do... But it's not something that happens overnight.